# botón de volver html+php+form

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-5

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario en html que tiene php de back end  para el submit.Uso el método post para tomar los datos del form y persistirlos en mysql.  Estoy utilizando el atributo "required" para la validación de campos de entrada, pero no sé como hacer el botón que me permita redirigir a otra página php en el caso de no rellenar los campos y que a la vez el botón quede dentro del form sin usar javascript. Estoy usando bootstrap 5 para los estilos.

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué no quieres usar Javascript? Si no lo usas tendrás que viajar al servidor para validar allí, lo cual no tendría sentido. Por poner un ejemplo, es como si tuvieras un mejor producto donde vives y te vas a 500 kilómetros a comprar un producto similar, pero de peor calidad. No lo digo porque el servidor sea de peor calidad, sino porque puedes validar perfectamente y sencillamente usando Javascript, sin gastar demasiados recursos y de una forma amigable para el usuario. Por ejemplo, puedes dejar el botón `Enviar` desactivado hasta que no se llenen todos los campos.

Comment: "Redirigir a otra página y a la vez quede dentro del form" esto no tiene sentido alguno. Quiero irme pero a la vez quedarme? O te vas de la página, o te quedas en el formulario. De cualquier manera, dado que no usas JS una vez llegas al servidor puedes redirigir al usuario a dónde te plazca con php, no sé cual es exactamente el problema... excepto el querer estar en dos sitios a la vez, y con eso no podemos ayudarte, porque no es posible

Answer (score 0):

La etiqueta `<form>` debe tener una propiedad `action=''`  (vacía), de esa manera cuando envíes el formulario siempre te mantienes en la misma página. Al inicio de la página y antes del código del formulario, colocas el código php que verifica la información del formulario y la envía a la base de datos o genera el mensaje de error (por ejemplo abriendo un `modal` o creando una variable de error que luego mostrarás usando un `alert`).

Esto funciona pero no es tan eficiente como validar usando javascript.